# Merge Hashmaps retaining values JAVA

Tags: java, merge, hashmap

Say I have two hashmaps:

1. {dog=1, cat=1, sport=3, golf=4}
2. {dog=5, person=1, animal=4}

I want to merge them retaining the values, so that the values add together in the output

**Output:**

{**dog=6**, person=1, animal=4, cat=1, sport=3, golf=4}

Notice how "dog" has a value of 6 *(5+1)*

*Using Hashmap.putAll(), the value of dog becomes 5,* any ideas how I can merge these retaining the values?

Many thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HashMap merged = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String x : map1.getKeySet()) {
   Integer y = map2.get(x);
   if (y == null) {
      merged.put(x, map1.get(x));
   } else {
      merged.put(x, map1.get(x)+y);
   }
}

for (String x : map2.getKeySet()) {
   if (merged.get(x) == null) {
      merged.put(x, map2.get(x));
   }
}
```

Just threw that together - not saying it's the best way.

Answer (score 6):

Google's open source [Guava Library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a class called [`Multiset`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) which entirely abstracts out the need for a `Map<T,Integer>` for counting instances of `T`.

You'll find that using `Multiset<String>` instead of using a `Map<String,Integer>` will result in less code which is less error prone to do the same thing.

Using `Multiset`, to merge the two you would just say:

```
multiset1.addAll(multiset2);
```

Comment: While a good answer, adding a 3rd party library to do a simple merge seems a bit overkill - not a lot about this code that is "error prone"

Comment: @Gandalf: I agree with all points in your comment. For the record, I like the `Multiset` approach not because it's less "error prone" but because it seems like the best data structure for the job. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the larger one, and loop along the smaller one, adding the nonexisting entries, and adjusting the value for existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a duplicate key, value into a map in java it will replace whatever value was previously there.

You could check to see if the value exists
so

```
Map outputMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map1.entrySet()){
   if(map2.contains(entry.getKey()){
     outputMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() + map2.get(entry.getKey());
     map2.remove(entry.getKey());  
   }
   else
     outputMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()
}
outputMap.addAll(map2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the simplest non destructive way to do it although it might not be as efficient as two loops since both keysets are inserted into a 3rd.

```
HashSet<String> allKeys = new HashSet<String>();
HashMap<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
allKeys.addAll(map1.keySet());
allKeys.addAll(map2.keySet());
for (String k : allKeys) {
  int i1 = map1.containsKey(k) ? map1.get(k) : 0;
  int i2 = map2.containsKey(k) ? map2.get(k) : 0;
  resultMap.put(k, i1 + i2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten the loops you can.

```
Map<String, Integer> merged = new HashMap<String, Integer>(map1); 
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
   Integer y = merged.get(entry.getKey()); 
   merged.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() + (y == null ? 0 : y));
}
```